# WPF designer (xdesproc) and x64 targeting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, designer

I've got some assemblies that must target the x64 platform.  They are dependencies that are referenced by WPF xaml projects.  So I didn't hesitate to start changing the target platform of these WPF projects to x64 as well (instead of AnyCPU).

But now the WPF designer (xdesproc) is getting pretty upset with me, and I'm getting weird little problems that I never had before, eg:

> The local property "Image" can only be applied to types that are derived from "IconButton".

Is the WPF designer going to support projects where the platform target is changed to x64?  I noticed that xdesproc itself runs in 32 bit mode so maybe it will just rejects all assemblies other than ones that target AnyCPU.

At runtime I have no problems.  The only problems are in the designer surface.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: After a bit more research, I have more detail. Not only is the designer unhappy that the WPF project in question is x64, but if I switch to AnyCPU the problem won't stop.  The xaml designer doesn't want *any* other project references to be targeting x64 either.

This seems like a huge inconvenience.  I guess I've been lucky that up until now I've never had dependencies that required the x64 platform.

I suppose my workaround will be to have bogus "AnyCPU" project configurations that won't be used in real life, but will only serve the purpose of making the designer happy.  Any other ideas?

Comment: The WPF designer for .net core 3 seems to be able to run in 64-bit.  Hopefully some of our projects can migrate to core soon.